# I want to configure a text editor(geany) to execute files in my windows 10 machine I use puthon3.7

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.7, geany, anaconda3

I tried the steps [HERE](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/) to try get my path interpreter location which I need to configure my text editor(geany). After inserting the path location in the compile and execute fields in the text editor text editor I got a message saying

> ‘c:\user\name’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: what's the result of `where python` in your anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are installing python using anaconda/miniconda installer then following the guide [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/), you have to

1. open Anaconda Prompt
2. run `where python` in the command line
3. copy the **first line** of the result text which looks like this `c:\user\patrick\Anaconda3\python.exe`
   note that it is your folder in your computer, which means patrick could be named differently based on your username, and mostly it is not `c:\users\name`
4. put that path to your custom build command of your geany, if you want to execute your file it would be like this `"c:/users/patrick/Anaconda3/python.exe" %f`

Please note the quote is mandatory if you have spaces in one of the folder names (which is totally okay and common in non-linux / non-mac folders).

You can use either forward or backward slash for the path separator.

Comment: thank you for responding. I followed the steps you listed above and I was able to get the file path, but after I put the path into the custom build command I still get the same error mentioned in my question

Comment: what is the output of `where python` command in your anaconda prompt? what is the text you input into the geany custom build command?

Comment: The output for the where python command was “c:\users\AGHOGHO ODIETE\Anaconda3\python.exe” and the exact inputs in the geany command prompts are: for compile c:\users\AGHOGHO ODIETE\Anaconda3\python.exe -m py_compile ”%f” and for execute  c:\users\AGHOGHO ODIETE\Anaconda3\python.exe “%f”

Comment: hi Patrick, the problem is that you have whitespace in your username folder. u have to wrap the path with quote, so put "c:\users\AGHOGHO ODIETE\Anaconda3\python.exe" “%f”. i updated my answer regarding to this